# Providing drawables for different devices

Tags: android, android-layout

Essentially, an application should support various devices. I'm using these guides: [mult.screen.supp](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing), [screen.stat](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens).

Design for both tablets and handsets on most of the activities is similar. What i'm puzzled about is how to provide drawables for both versions knowing that their density groups provide different resolutions and hence the drawables are not substitutable.

For example, compare xlarge(tablet) - mdpi to normal(handset) - mdpi:

1. Normal screen, Medium density (160), mdpi: 320x480
2. Extra Large screen, Medium density (160), mdpi: 1280x800

So, if I create foo.png(50px x 50px) for the first group and then test the same layout

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/foo" />
```

on the second group, which will lookup for the same image in the mdpi folder, - the image will look tiny.

I have a solution but I'm not sure whether I'm doing it right:

- Create attr.xml for each Screen size configuration.
- Create `<item name="foo" type="drawable">@drawable/h_foo</item>` in handset-resources folders, which references image with appropriate for `normal(handset) - mdpi`  resolution h_foo, say 50x50.
- Create `<item name="foo" type="drawable">@drawable/t_foo</item>` in tablet-resources folders, which references image with appropriate for `xlarge(tablet) - mdpi`  resolution t_foo, say 150x150.

Could you elucidate whether this approach is fine and what are other solutions out there ?

Comment: try the [Android assets studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html)

Comment: Read more caredfully http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better when you keep the same resource name and just use different folders to put the actual png:

```
drawable-mdpi        -> used for normal screens
drawable-large-mdpi  -> used for large screens
```

See [providing resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) for the available configuration qualifiers.

Comment: okay, thanks - I'll give it a try. multiple screen guide also notices more precise control with sw600dp and similar folders. My point is tha t if I to provide for both /laoyut-large and /layout-sw600dp the same drawables I

Comment: you just need to provide the resources that are different into `drawable-large-mdpi`. If a resource is not found there the system will fall back to `drawable-mdpi`.

Comment: This is fine until you're forced to duplicate the resources in drawable-large-mdpi into drawable-normal-hdpi. Assuming you want higher DPI resources of course.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplicates I keep all my images in the drawable-nodpi folder, and suffix the file names with a size (e.g. image-small.png, image-medium.png etc). Then I have XML definitions in the device-specific (drawable-normal-mdpi, drawable-large-mdpi) folders for each item. For example:

drawable-normal-mdpi/image.xml:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:src="@drawable/image-medium" />
```

drawable-large-mdpi/image.xml:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:src="@drawable/image-large" />
```

Note that I saw a comment on here from a Google engineer (can't find it now) that didn't recommend this functionality, but until someone comes up with a better solution (that is compatible with older Android versions) then I'm sticking with it.